# How to set bluimp filedir with $_GET[]

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Hi I try to use **[bluimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)** file upload. On my system there are many folders. For each product id I created different folders to store product images and folder names are related with product id

For example I have a product and its product id is 123, so I have a folder like:

```
/images/123/
```

Also I have an admin panel to edit product info. Now I want to upload multiple images to product related upload folder.

In admin panel I reach every item with its product id like

```
http://www.example.com/admin/edit.php?ProductId=123
```

My question is: How to change blueimp upload directory via `$_GET["ProductId"]`

I just find this, related to my question. But If I want to use url parameter how must my `option` array?

Thanks

```
$uplDir = $_SESSION["uploadDirectory"].'/;

$option = array(
    /* some options */
    'upload_dir' => $uplDir,

    /* .... */
);
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($option);
```

Comment: probably not a good idea to have a different directory for each product image

Comment: @Dagon Every product has about 300,400 images

Comment: ok, well my guess is : `$uplDir = '/images/'. $_GET["ProductId"].'/';`

Comment: I know how to use get parameter. But product edit and file upload pages are in different locations on my server. How to pass $_GET["dir"] value to bluimp's index.php?

Comment: don't understand what you are asking

Comment: It does not matter where those pages are, its all about where the index.php is. And for that you can just change it within the url option when initializing the plugin.